# squid configuration linux step

Tags: linux, unix, squid

Hi everyone, 

Can someone explain me this configuration commands

```
cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 4096 16 256

acl all src 0/0
acl cacheProto proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl authorizedPorts port 80 443
acl SSLPort port 443
acl connect method CONNECT
acl myNetwork src 192.168.82.0/24

http_access allow cacheProto localhost
http_access deny cacheProto
http_access deny !authorizedPorts
http_access deny connect !SSLPort
http_access allow myNetwork

http_access deny all
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs? http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_dir/ if you have any specific doubts, maybe it can be asked specifically, dont expect someone to explain whole sections of config file here.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/network-administrations/squid-server.html) is a great tutorial that I used a few days ago when I had to set up squid on my server.

Alternatively, if you want a really detailed explanation of what each option does, check [this](http://www.deckle.co.uk/squid-users-guide/squid-configuration-basics.html) tutorial by Oskar Pearson. It includes not only configuration explanations, but an entire [user guide](http://www.deckle.co.uk/squid-users-guide/).

You may also consider skimming through the [official docs](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/).